# Mod_Rewrite file to subfolder in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a folder to a file.
I want to redirect:

> www.mysite.com/category/customername

AND

> www.mysite.com/category/customername/

TO

> www.mysite.com/category.php?customer=customername

This is working, but "customer" become "customername.php" and not "customer"

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ category.php?customer=$1 [L]
```

How could i remove ".php" via .htaccess?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^category/([\s\w-]+)/?$ category.php?customer=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: mmm no.. is not working:
RewriteRule ^category/(\w+)$ category.php?customer=$1 [L, NC, QSA]

Comment: what does "NC" and "QSA" mean? is necessary the question mark after dollar?

Comment: hi. this is not working when there are some blank spaces or minus (-). is it normal?

Comment: /? Is used to allow a trailing slash. NC is for honor case. QSA is for keeping any existing query string.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you anubhava, i have do a dynamic rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/(\w+)/?$ $1.php?customer=$2 [L]
```

Tested for

> www.mysite.com/category_1/customer AND
>   www.mysite.com/category_1/customer/
>   www.mysite.com/category_2/customer AND
>   www.mysite.com/category_2/customer/
>   www.mysite.com/category_X/customer AND
>   www.mysite.com/category_X/customer/

Bye